# Hover unrelated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've read related articles how to change on hover some unrelated divs. But could not find what i needed.

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>

   <div class="pframe">
        <div class="img1"></div>
   </div>
```

I want on hover of the `.item1` class change the css of `.img1`
with `box-shadow: 0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85);`
and when I hover over `.img1` it changes the css of `.item1` with `background-color: rgba(0,141,183,0.9)`

If it is impossible to do with css parent - child relation, how could Implement or jquery?

Comment: Is there more than one `img` div? Like `img2`, `img3`, etc.

Comment: yes, there are several of them

Comment: So, you want to match all of the divs with the images with the same numbers?

Comment: Like `item1` with `img1`, `item2` with `img2`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery it is easy to implement.

```
$(function(){
    var item = $('.item1');
    var img1 = $('.img1');

    item.mouseover(function() {
        img1.css({"box-shadow": "0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85)"});
    }).mouseout(function() {
        img1.css({"box-shadow": "none"});
    });


    img1.mouseover(function() {
        item.css({"background-color": "rgba(0,141,183,0.9)"});
    }).mouseout(function() {
        item.css({"background-color": "transparent"});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired functionality with jquery using this piece of code:

```
$(function(){
    var item = $('.item1');
    var img1 = $('.img1');
    item.on('mouseover',function(){
        img1.css('box-shadow','0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85)');
    });
    img1.on('mouseover', function(){
        item.css('background-color','rgba(0,141,183,0.9)');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!!

Comment: Glad, It helped. Welcome to SO!!

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lv75gpek/1/)**

Well you need to target specific elements with its last character then and here is how it is:

```
var clas="";//global variables
var lastChar="";
//attach mouseover event on element whose class starts with item
$('div[class^="item"]').on('mouseover',function(){
    clas=$(this).attr('class'); //get the class of current element
    lastChar = clas.substr(clas.length - 1); //get its last character
    $(".pframe").find('.img'+lastChar).css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85)'); //find it in pframe and add css
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(".pframe").find('.img'+lastChar).css('box-shadow', 'none');
    //remove once mouseout
});

//attach mouseover event on element whose class starts with img
$('div[class^="img"]').on('mouseover',function(){
    clas=$(this).attr('class');
    lastChar = clas.substr(clas.length - 1) 
    $(".sidebar").find('.item'+lastChar).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,141,183,0.9)');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(".sidebar").find('.item'+lastChar).css('background-color', '');
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lv75gpek/3/)**

As @roullie pointed out this will fail on and after 10th item as we always fetch last character. So if you edit your html and add class like `item_1`, `item_2` as well as `img_1` and `img_2` then you can use below method to pop out exact `elements`.

```
var clas="";//global variables
var lastChar="";
//attach mouseover event on element whose class starts with item
$('div[class^="item_"]').on('mouseover',function(){
    clas=$(this).attr('class'); //get the class of current element
    lastChar = clas.split('_')[1]; //split _ and get its exact character to match
    $(".pframe").find('.img_'+lastChar).css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85)'); //find it in pframe and add css
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(".pframe").find('.img_'+lastChar).css('box-shadow', 'none');
    //remove once mouseout
});

//attach mouseover event on element whose class starts with img
$('div[class^="img_"]').on('mouseover',function(){
    clas=$(this).attr('class');
    lastChar = clas.split('_')[1]; 
    $(".sidebar").find('.item_'+lastChar).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,141,183,0.9)');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(".sidebar").find('.item_'+lastChar).css('background-color', '');
});
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. however will fail on `item10` or greater than

Comment: @roullie.. thanks for pointing out.. provided an alternate way.. but since the OP is new guy he might not even see this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with css
Try this

```
.item1:hover .img1{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85);
}
```

Comment: There is more than one

Comment: The problem is that the divs are not related.

Comment: Ok you want that specific item change css for specific img div then you have to write css for each div otherwise general css will work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is not a duplicate of some post, but here is how you could achieve this with jquery.

```js
    $('.item1').mouseover(function(e) {
      $('.img1').css({
        "box-shadow": "0px 0px 43px 9px rgba(56,112,255,0.85)"
        });
    }); //Getting to the image box shadow from mouse over event in class item1

    $('.img1').mouseover(function(e) {
      $('item1').css({
        "box-shadow": "background-color: rgba(0,141,183,0.9)"
        });
     }); //Getting to the image box shadow from mouse over event in image
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="item1"></div>
        <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>

       <div class="pframe">
            <div class="img1"></div>
       </div>
```